three-prong plug doesn't fit in any socket
I'm totally dumbfounded by this. I have an electrical cable with a three-prong plug. It works fine in my house and at many other places I've taken it so far. This weekend I'm visiting a friend and it doesn't fit in any of the sockets in their house. I compared it with another plug which fits fine and it doesn't seem to me like there is any difference. In the attached picture the black cable fits, the white one doesn't.


Are the pins all identical in size and spacing? Is one, or more, bent?

It is most likely a "tamper resistant" receptacle. One of the banes of electrical code (mis)management. If you look closely, you may see a "TR" embossed on one of faces of the outlet. You need to carefully insert it so it goes in evenly or something like that.

Some outlets are also tighter than others and need more force to put in/take out.  Tight is gooder/too loose is bader.  All plugs/outlets of the same type should be standard size.

@SolarMike They are all straight and look the same to me sizewise.

A view of the ends of the plugs might be helpful.

What actually prevents the plug from being inserted into a socket? Which part of it did not fit?

As @Jack states, one likely issue is fitting it into a tamper-resistant outlet. If there are little shutters in the outlet blocking the two flat blades, be careful to insert the round ground prong first, and wiggle it a bit, to pop open those shutters.

It is most likely a "tamper resistant" receptacle. One of the banes of electrical code (mis)management. If you look closely, you may see a "TR" embossed on one of faces of the outlet. You need to carefully insert it so it goes in evenly or something like that.
